# No AIMP taskbar animation when playing radio

Tags: audio, windows-10, taskbar, aimp

When I play radio stations with AIMP 4 my taskbar icon is animated. How can I stop that animation as I find it distracting?

- No animation when I play audio files from disk - all good
- Have disabled the Win 10 performance property for icon animation which does not help

  Unfortunately I can not take a snapshot of the animation, but it is kind of changing color gradient when playing streams.

[image: State1]
[image: State2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's from the newest version, but it might help someone:

[image]